# jQuery param - deep serialization with dots instead of square brackets?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is there a way to get jQuery `$.param` to generate notation with dots instead of square brackets, to work with ASP.NET or Spring?

`$.param({nested: {foo: 'bar'}})` will return something like `nested%5Bfoo%5D=bar` (URL encoded `nested[foo]=bar`).  I would *like* it to return `nested.foo=bar` instead, so it would work with ASP.NET parameter binding.

Is that just not possible with jQuery?  Is the only option to send the object as a JSON string and parse it on the server side explicitly, or POST the JSON as the request body and let the framework parse it?

Comment: `nested[foo] !== nested.foo` necessarily... first `foo` is a variable not an object property so unless `var foo = 'foo'` they do not equate.

Comment: clarified that I was talking about the generated URL parameter string coming out of `$.param`